# magento order email send without make payment of ccavenue

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

[image]
i click on place order button after selecting payment method.my url is redirected to cc-avenue payment environment.but order email was send without make payment.

i use ccavenue extension by bluezeal

please help for that

thanks in advance

Comment: get the official extension from ccavenue team

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply .i can't find official extension please give me link .

Comment: please contact ccavenue team.